# PHP bind_param fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fatal-error, mysql-error-1064

Need some help here, theres a fatal error when I try to bind.

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.

Please help :(

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shopp"); //connect to database
if (!$connection){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno()); //return error is connect fail
}

$query= $connection->prepare("select * from login where (USERNAME=?,PASSWORD=?");

$username=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

 $query ->bind_param('ss',$password,$username);

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: web.html"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
header("location: loginerror.html");
}

?>
```

The error is at this line:

```
$query ->bind_param('ss',$password,$username);
```

Comment: why are using mysql_* extension here?

Comment: for fatal error use this $query->bind_param('ss',$password,$username);

Comment: You can't mix drivers, `mysqli` doesn't work with `mysql_*`. I've also never seen this syntax before `where (USERNAME=?,PASSWORD=?)`, does that work in your DB interface?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query, and you BLINDLY assumed that nothing could ever go wrong with your query, hence taking the boolean false that mysqli returned and trying to use it as an object. Plus, you need to learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Using placeholders and then STILL trying to (incorrectly) manually escape is a strong indication of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: The fatal error clearly tells you that `$query` is not an object, it's a boolean value `false`, which means your prepare statement has failed.

Comment: whats wrong with the prepare statement?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` for the where clause, that also doesn't appear to be valid SQL. I think it should be where `username = ? and password = ?`.

Comment: still got error. isit a valid SQL?

Comment: Same error? Have you corrected the other issues? Update your question to your current code.. Use the `@` if addressing comments to a user.

Comment: While the linked duplicate is not the correct duplicate, it is still a problem in this code. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) and the documentation for the call you made for more details about the error you received.